# Use JMX (MBean) to log WebLogic status

Tags: weblogic, logging, jmx

I know we can use MBean to get WebLogic's status. For example, use JDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBean (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13951/core/index.html) to get the JDBC status. And use other MBeans, we can also get the status of EJB, WebService, ...

But this is just the status at that time, if I want to monitor the history, for example, I want to know the detail run time of every EJB transaction, is it possible?

The purpose is we want to monitor our application performance, an obvious solution is add log in our EJB and parse it. But if we can get it from server without write code, it will be better.

Another question is, since JMX is a standard and JBoss supports it. If the solution can support both WebLogic and JBoss will be better.

## Update:

I read the WebLogic document and found that [WLDF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/wldf_configuring/intro.html) is good.

- Collected Metrics: This can collect server information. I use it to collect JDBC status into a database.
- Instrumentation: I use this to record the execute time of a method

The following are the official document and a tutorial.

**Collected Metrics**

- Official doc: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/wldf_configuring/config_harvester.html
- Blog tutorial: http://weblogic-server.blogspot.com/2009/12/configuration-diagnostics-jdbc-store.html

**Instrumentation:**

- Official doc: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/wldf_configuring/config_instrumentation.html
- Blog tutorial: http://m-button.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-wldf-to-trace-time-taken-by-your.html

The only inconvenient is the syntax of pointcut. If I want to monitor several methods in a class, I need to write several wldf-instrumentation-monitor tags. Unless I can find a wild card pattern to describe them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible but it might be easier for you to use the existing [WLDF](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13714/toc.htm) framework - You can define which MBeans you want to track, store historical data to a filestore and graph them within the console.

I don't recommend the route of logging debug statements, especially in a production environment. Depending on the throughput of your system, the additional I/O from logging can be a significant overhead.

JMX is the standard way to access your runtime beans but they are going to differ between WebLogic and JBoss. In my personal experience, unless you're using an enterprise solution such as CA Wily's Introscope, you're better off using the individual programs written specifically for the application server as they usually highlight other metrics you may be interested in (If you have the time to traverse all MBeans and determine how useful they are, this may not be of concern).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I just use Collected Metrics and Instrumentation of WLDF, it's really good. I save the information to another database and analyze them. And is there a similar for JBoss?

Comment: Yes, I think the JBoss equivalent is called Web Console. I'm not familiar with JBoss On (JON) but it may be worth looking into as well.

Comment: In the instrumentation, I still have 2 requirements. 1st is could I know the message size? I found there is a payload field, but it's blob? 2nd, is it possible to know the method is success or has exception?

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be best if you post it as a new question with the requirements and details around the MBeans you are accessing.

Comment: I post another questions, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935583/how-to-monitor-method-execption-and-size-in-weblogic-by-wdlfs-instrumentation